# setTimeLimit() internal behavior

Tags: r, timeout, timeoutexception

Could someone walk me through the specific side effects and internals of `base::setTimeLimit()`?

Reason: I am trying to impose optional timeouts for [drake targets](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/issues/76), and I turned to `R.utils::withTimeout()`, which uses `base::setTimeLimit()`. Drake timeouts work in an interactive R session, but they are unreliable when I test them into [unit tests](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-retry.R#L43). I want to dig into the ways that `base::setTimeLimit()` modifies the global environment so I can do more debugging.

Comment: For what it's worth, `R.utils` has package tests for `withTimeout()` asserting that it works (also in non-interactive mode as in R CMD check), cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.utils/blob/master/tests/withTimeout.R

Comment: @HenrikB sorry, I did not mean to point the finger at `R.utils`. I was just baffled by some of the inconsistencies in `drake` timeouts. I simplified some of the exception handling last night, and I cannot seem to reproduce any of the old errors I was getting. But I still want to know how `base::setTimeLimit()` works on the inside.

Comment: No worries, that's not how I took it.  I just shared facts that might rule out certain things in the troubleshooting forest.